# How change the language of window after window loaded in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `WPF` application with `C#`, i want to convert the language of the window depending on the user selection. for user selection i have `ComboBox` with language names. 
what i want is when user select the Combo form `controls` labels/text should change to that language.

i already tried this : [Multilanguage in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814600/multilanguage-in-wpf) but 
its very complicated.

can anyone please tell me the easy way to achieve it?

Comment: you many wan't to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268699/mvvm-conform-localization-in-wpf-applications

Comment: I'm using https://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com and it's actually very simple to use. What do you not understand about it? Read the manual first.

Comment: @Joel: I dont know the MVVM i have never used that. :(

Comment: @L-Three : very nice! +1 for you!

Comment: it has nothing to do with the mvvm pattern, it is about localizing wpf application with resource files (*.resx). The short answer to your question is: Changing the language in WPF <b>during runtime</b> is complicated.